# Fingerprint Reader only works to log in Thinkpad T440p Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, thinkpad, fingerprint-reader

I just did a clean install of *Ubuntu 20.04* on the hard drive in my Ultrabay.  *Fingerprint reader not working in Terminal* or when installing apps with Software Installer.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to update the Pluggable Authentication Modules package. Fortunately, it's not too difficult.

1. Open a terminal and type: `sudo pam-auth-update`
   [image: PAM Package Configuration]
2. Use the spacebar to enable "Fingerprint authentication"
3. Use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to highlight `<OK>`, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. Reboot

You should now be able to use your biometric device in a lot more places.

Comment: Good to go, Thank you